# Prove that the general following family of vectors are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

Given $a_0, a_1,...,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ all different numbers.

Demonstrate that the following vectors are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

$v_0=(1,a_0,a_0^2,...,a_0^n)$

$v_1=(1,a_1,a_1^2,...,a_1^n)$

$. . . $

$v_n=(1,a_n,a_n^2,...,a_n^n)$

$(1)$ Dimonstrate that is enough by showing that are linearly independent.

$(2)$ Generalize for every n by using Gauss elimination.

I recall the definition of linear independence as follows to use for $(1)$

> Given $\left(v_i\right)_{i=1,..,k}$ as a family of $k$ vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is *linearly independent* **if and only if**:
> $$\forall\lambda_1,\lambda_2,..\lambda_p\in\mathbb{R},\hspace{12pt}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_iv_i=0_{\mathbb{R}^n}\right)\hspace{-3pt}\Longrightarrow\hspace{-3pt}\left(\lambda_1=\lambda_2=..=\lambda_k=0\right)$$

Isn't my intention to ask for an exhaustive solution but for help given that I don't even know how to start with the point $(1)$ neither $(2)$. So please, I kindly ask for some orientation?

Comment: Cf. Vandermonde determinant

Comment: Normally I should solve this without the knowledge of the existence of any kind of determinant.

Answer (score 1):

A linear system with such vectors as lines arises naturally when dealing with polynomial interpolation (The rhs is assembled with the values of the function to be interpolated at $x = a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n$). As it was mentioned in a comment, this matrix is usually denoted as the VanderMonde matrix, which is invertible as long as the $a_i$'s are distinct. You can easily compute the determinant and see it is nonzero. This guarantees that all the lines are linearly independent. I'm not sure what 2. means... There is nothing to be generalised.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to solve it in that direction but I believe that this solution must be achieved without the usage of any determinant. In relation to (2), a previous point that I didn't write was requesting to show the tesis for n=1,2 using Gauss elimination. Then, in the next point they asked generalize this for any n.

Comment: I mentioned the determinant because it is a well known result that the lines of a square matrix are linearly independent if and only if the determinant is not zero. But, if you prefer, you can just row reduce the matrix.